# MATLAB: Approximate tomorrow's temperature with 2nd, 3rd and 4th polynomial using the Least Squares method.

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, matlab, least-squares

The following is Exercise 3 of a Numerical Analysis task I have to do as part of my university course on the subject.

> Find an approximation of tomorrow's temperature based on the last 23
>   values of hourly temperature of your city ( Meteorological history for
>   Thessaloniki {The city of my univ} can be found here:
>   http://freemeteo.com)
>
> You will approximate the temperature function with a polynomial of
>   2nd, 3rd and 4th degree, using the Least Squares method. Following
>   that, you will find the value of the function at the point that
>   interests you. Compare your approximations qualitatively and make a
>   note to the time and date you're doing the approximation on.

Maybe it's due to fatigue due to doing the first two tasks without break, or it's my lack of experience on numerical analysis, but I am completely stumped. I do not even know where to start.

I know it's disgusting to ask for a solution without even showing signs of effort, but I would appreciate anything. Leads, tutorials, outlines of the things I need to work on, one after the other, anything.

I'd be very much obliged to you.

**NOTE**: I am not able to use any MATLAB in-built approximation functions.

Comment: The polyfit command is your friend. Cheers!

Comment: @Dmoreno I apologise, see the edit.

Comment: Can you use Excel ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'd prefer to work through Matlab, what did you have in mind?

Comment: @DimitrisS.Sorry, I thought that you were not able to use Matlab. If you cannot use the least square polynomial fir from Matlab, then you must code the method. This is quite simple : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Comment: @DimitrisS.: See the example here for order 2. You have more daa points, but that is not an issue. This shows you the form of the matrix, all calculations and how to solve. At least set up the data and matrix for second order and then use the typical matrix items in matlab to solve. http://kobus.ca/seminars/ugrad/NM5_curve_s02.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathbf{t}\in\mathbb{R}^{23}$ be the last 23 samples you have. To fit these to an $N^\mathrm{th}$ order  polynomial in terms of the hour, i.e., $t = \sum_i p_i h^i$, where $\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is the vector of coefficients and $h\in\mathbb{R}$ is the time in hours, first set up the system using the measurements you have and the times at which they were taken. According to the problem, the times were taken at $h = 0,1,\dots$, so let us define $h_i$ to be equal to the value $i$. Then

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
h_0^0 & h_0^1 & h_0^2 & h_0^3 & \cdots \\
h_1^0 & h_1^1 & h_1^2 & h_1^3 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \ddots
\end{array}
\right]
\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{H} \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{t}
$$

If you write the above out in long form, you'll see that all it says is that

$$
p_0 \cdot h_i^0 + p_1 \cdot h_i^1 + p_2 \cdot h_i^3 + \dots = t_i
$$

Now to solve for $\mathbf{p}$, you just use the normal equation:

$$
\mathbf{p} = \left( \mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{H} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{t}
$$

In Matlab, setting up and solving for the above is straightforward. Once you have $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{t}$ defined,

```
p = (H' * H) \ H' * t;
```